# Why does AdaBoostClassifier with SVM work worse

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, adaboost

By working worse, I mean even a higher training error.

```
# Boosted SVC
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(random_state=1), random_state=1, algorithm="SAMME", n_estimators=5)
clf.fit(X, y)

# Only SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

My training data is

[image]

The result of boosted SVM:
[image]

And the result of SVM:

[image]

Comment: You should ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Also, i think that happens because boosting requires more variable (More possibilities to separate data) algorithms than linear, can you try non-linear svm?

Comment: Also, it's not implementation problem - it's some theoretical problem, i'm also intrested in getting answer for this question. I did same thing with AdaBoost self-made implementation , and it didn't worked properly too. Only with decision trees i achieved normal results.

Comment: @Olologin The default kernel for ``sklearn.svm.SVC`` is ``rbf``, which is non-linear.

Answer (score 2):

The main concept of adaBoost is to combine weak learners, thats why the default classifier is a decision stump. So by using SVM (strong classifier) as a weak one, you are loosing the concept of ensemble learning and you are getting worst results.

Comment: "So by using SVM (strong classifier) as a weak one" that's not true at all.... SVM is a weak classifier